# Output null when using ContractPromise for ink! v4 smart contract

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, substrate-front-end

I create a smart contract using ink! v4.2 and deploy it using contracts-ui.substrate.io
Then in my front (which uses @polkadot/api-contract: 10.7.2, @polkadot/api: 10.7.2) I run this code:

```js
await ApiPromise.create({ new WsProvider("wss://ws.test.azero.dev"), signer: connectedAccount });
const contract = new ContractPromise(api, abiDataJson, contractAddress);
```

Where,

api: is correct for sure

abiDataJson: json generated in /target/ink after run `cargo contract build --release`

contractAddress: obtained in contracts-ui.substrate.io in the part that shows "You instantiated this contract 5...", just below the title of the smart contract name

And when I run

```js
const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = await contract.query.totalSupply(account.address, { gasLimit: -1, storageDepositLimit: null });
console.log('result.toHuman(): ', result.toHuman());
console.log("output: ", output);
```

I obtain

```
result.toHuman():  {Err: {…}}
output: null
```

I think the error might be related to contractAddress, because if I put a different addres I get the same thing. In addition, the smart contract is deployed successfully as it works by calling it from contracts-ui.substrate.io

Anybody know where the error is?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The -1 value of `gasLimit` is generating the error. I solve it by modifying it in the following way:

```js
const gasLimit = api.registry.createType('WeightV2', { refTime: 3912368128, proofSize: 131072 });
```

Where `refTime` and `proofSize` values are obtained using contracts-ui.substrate.io